# error with advertising using admob

Tags: android, admob

I have an error using google admob. Everything works fine when the mobile screen is larger than 4", but if less, advertising will not be shown. On the emulator I get this error

> Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <240, 37>, you <216, 377>

this is my code

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads">

<com.google.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/lytMain"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="id"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

This is the java code

```
lytMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lytMain);
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "Num google");
lytMain.addView(adView);
adView.bringToFront();
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Not works in android 2.3 with screen of 4" :/ Only on screen above 4" and android  above 4.0

I edit the code and now see this error

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.ads.AdView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.


java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(    at com.google.ads.AdView.a(SourceFile:184)
    at com.google.ads.AdView.a(SourceFile:352)
    at com.google.ads.AdView.<init>(SourceFile:125)
```

Comment: please leave at least 320x50px for the `AdSize.BANNER`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to leave enough space both verically and horizontally for the ads to be shown. You will need to change your layout so that enough space (that is listed in the error message) is available on all devices and screen sizes.

Banner sizes are listed on [Admob page](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate). In case of `AdSize.BANNER`, it is 320x50.

Comment: I change now the layout create more space for the ad and nothing the error continuous look
LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lytMain"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: But do you actually provide that much space, considering other elements of the layout?

Comment: releases every layout and nothing :/ the layout is very small and nothing

Comment: Can you try it in an empty activity with no other elements?

Comment: Wait I will delete the buttons
 for see that happened

Comment: BTW, you don't really need any code, as you have `ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"`.

Comment: yes man :( 
You have skype  I don't know that more tried this is my first app @Szymon

Answer (score 0):

Better to wrap AdView using RelativeLayout. This is my working configuration to use BANNER Admob.

In my XML file, i wrap my Ads in RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/layout" >
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="youradsid"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the **com.google.ads.AdView** element in a layout. If you are using LinearLayout use gravity to give it enough space to meet the minimum space criteria. Remember, ad's have images and text that need a minimum space on the screen.

I suggest that you use a high level RelativeLayout, and **overlay** the **com.google.ads.AdView** element bottom center. That way, regardless of how you orient some of your content will be overlayed with the ad.

Comment: make width, fill_parent and check.

Comment: nothing sent this error Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <240, 37>, Has: <216, 377>

Comment: Did not understand. Please rephrase.